# Why my parameter names in post requests being urlEncoded by jetty, and how to avoid it?

Tags: java, http, jetty, urlencode, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm sending post requests to a jetty server using httpClient.
With request header set as:
`'method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");'`
I found that, if my parameter name has a whitespace, it will be encoded to '+' by jetty. I say this is done by jetty because I didn't do that.
For example, if one of my post parameter name is 'id ', it will be transformed to 'id+' when I see it later in the servlet.
If I start this same web app in jboss server, it's all OK, 'id ' remains 'id ', nothing would be encoded.
Could someone tell me how to avoid this? Can jetty server behaves the same as jboss server on this issue? How to configure it?
Thanks!

Comment: Which httpclient do you mean, and which version? There are more than one.

Comment: Hi, I'm using httpClient 3.1. I don't think it's an httpClient issue. Because I tried both httpClient 3.x and 4.x. And the result is same. So I suspect if jetty did something on the parameter names.

Comment: It's apache httpClient 3.1

Comment: Can you post what you are doing jetty side in your servlet/handler? Also how you are constructing the requests on the client using http client. Also, what specific version of Jetty are you using?

Comment: I captured network packages using wireshark and found that all whitespaces are already urlEncoded when transmitting in the network. So this is done by httpClient but not jetty.  
And according to html spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 ,all param's names and values should be urlEncoded, so httpClient did it right. I don't know why jetty doesn't decode the parameter names while jboss does. I'm using jetty 7.2.